# Get the new row in grid

Tags: vb.net

I want to  add a new row in datagrid

Add new row

I want to add the new row in grid, then i want to focus that grid.  like this

```
grid1.addrow()
grid.newrow.focus() 'I want to focus into new row
```

How to do this.

Need suggestion or code help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really crude example, since I don't know how or with what you are populating your dgv control (I assume you mean "DataGridView" when you say "Grid"):

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = Me.DataGridView1
    Dim newRow As DataGridViewRow
    Dim rowData() As String = {"John", "Doe"}

    'Add a first row, just so we can see that this works:
    newRow = dgv.Rows(dgv.Rows.Add(rowData))
    newRow.Selected = False

    ' Now create some random data for the next row:
    rowData(0) = "Mary"
    rowData(1) = "Smith"

    ' Add the next row:
    newRow = dgv.Rows(dgv.Rows.Add(rowData))

    ' Set the status of the first cell (element zero in the array of cells
    ' to Selected = true:
    newRow.Cells(0).Selected = True

    'If you want a reference to the active cell:
    Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = newRow.Cells(0)

End Sub
```

That's not much to work with, but you didn't give us much to work with either . . . If you could post a little more of your code, or explain a little more fully what you are trying to do, we might be able to provide more constructive feedback.

Hope that helps!